# How to calculate the number of matching elements in a list (as a pandas column) in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

After many failing tries I am asking for help to solve this. Say, I have a list

`target = [1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994]`

and a data frame `stnYrs` as

```
STATION        YEARS
A             [1990,1994,1995,1996,1998,2000]
B             [1992,1995,2001]
C             [1988,1989]
```

I would like to create a new column `NYEAR` in `stnYrs`, as the number of matching years in column `YEARS` found in `target`. What is the pythonic way to do this?
The result should be like

```
STATION        YEARS                           NYEAR
A             [1990,1994,1995,1996,1998,2000]  2
B             [1992,1995,2001]                 1
C             [1988,1989]                      0
```

Edit 1 -

I tried the methods suggested by Chris and YO. Both work if I use testing examples for `target` and `stnYrs`. However, in my real application, neither gave the right answer. I always get zero for `NYEAR`. I just do not know why. Here are the lines in my code:

```
stnYrs = pd.read_csv('isd_stnNyr_duOnly.txt',dtype={'STATION':'str'})
periods = [(1971,1980),(1981,1990),(1991,2000),(2001,2010)]
for iperd, perd in enumerate(periods):
    ybgn, yend = perd
    target = list(range(ybgn,yend+1))
    stnYrs['NYEAR'] = stnYrs['YEARS'].apply(lambda x: sum(1 for yr in x if yr in target))
    ...
```

`stnYrs[['STATION','YEARS','NYEAR']].head()` gives

> STATION                                      YEARS      NYEAR
>   0  78982099999          [1959, 1960, 1974, 1975, 1976...]      0
>
> 1  69205499999                                      na      0
>
> 2  40941099999                      [1976, 1977, 1978]      0
>
> 3  40942099999          [1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980...]      0

The `isd_stnNyr_duOnly.txt` file looks like

> STATION,COUNTRY,GROUP,SOURCE,LAT,LON,ELEVATION,YEARS
>   78982099999,AA,SAM,4,12.501,-70.015,18.28,"[1959, 1960, 1974, 1975,
>   1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986,
>   1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1993, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001,
>   2004, 2008]"
>
> 69205499999,AF,SAS,4,32.8,67.633,1989.0,na
>
> 40941099999,AF,SAS,4,34.883,65.3,2070.0,"[1976, 1977, 1978]"
>
> 40942099999,AF,SAS,4,33.533,65.267,2183.0,"[1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1983, 1984, 2010, 2019]"

Edit 2-

I finally figured out how to convert `YEARS` column to list.

`def clean(seq_string):
    return list(map(int, seq_string.strip("[]").split(',')))`

`stnrec = pd.read_csv('isd_stnNyr_duOnly.txt',dtype={'STATION':'str'},converters={'YEARS': clean})`

Comment: `stnYrs["NYEAR"] = stnYrs["YEARS"].apply(lambda x: np.intersect1d(x,target).size)` ?

Comment: @thushv89 That may fail if `YEARS` contain duplicated years

Comment: Your `'YEARS'` column is actually a string. You have to provide `dtype={'STATION':'str', 'YEARS': 'list'})`

Comment: I had the feeling that data type may be the issue, but in this case, `'YEARS': 'list'` does not work. got error `data type "list" not understood`

Comment: @Xin Try the same thing without the quotes around `list`.

Comment: does not work even without quotes. `TypeError: dtype '<class 'list'>' not understood
`

Answer (score 1):

Let us do

```
stnYrs['NYEAR']=pd.DataFrame(stnYrs["YEARS"].tolist()).isin(target).sum(1).values
```

Comment: Nice, this works on testing example, but not in my code due to other reasons. I am wondering why (see my edit).

Comment: Sorry to say, but this solution is around 450% time of the one proposed by @Chris.

Answer (score 1):

Using `pandas.DataFrame.apply` with built-in `sum`:

```
stnYrs['NYEAR'] = stnYrs['YEARS'].apply(lambda x: sum(1 for i in x if i in target))
print(stnYrs)
```

Output:

```
  STATION                                 YEARS  NYEAR
0       A  [1990, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1998, 2000]      2
1       B                    [1992, 1995, 2001]      1
2       C                          [1988, 1989]      0
```

Comment: Nice, this works on testing example, but not in my code due to other reasons. I am wondering why (see my edit).